# Java Tomcat log4j can not find appender

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

When executing my application i got:
No appenders could be found for logger (org.displaytag.properties.TableProperties)

But i have /usr/share/tomcat-7/webapps/sample2/WEB-INF/classes/mypackage/log4j.properties
(where all java files are located) with content:

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, org.displaytag.properties.TableProperties
log4j.appender.org.displaytag.properties.TableProperties=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

Why Log4j can not find that appender ?

I have tried to put log4j.properties in multiple other locations +restart tomcat but it did not help.

Thanks,

Comment: Sorry - my fault - i did forgot to init Properties in my app listener.

Comment: No need to be sorry. Add the solution as an answer :)